# Easy way to create object with members of various datatypes

Tags: c++, c++11, object, constructor, initialization

In C++, I often need to use an extremely simple, primative object containing a variety of datatypes simply so that I can pass it around easily between functions.  In Python, I achieve this by using dictionaries.  For example:

```
easy = {"keyframe_range":[], "value":0.25, "interpolation":"bezier"}
```

However, in C++, if I wanted to create something similar, I would need to:

```
struct obj
{
  vector<int> keyframe_range;
  float value;
  string interpolation;

  obj(vector<int> vv, float ff, string ss) : keyframe_range(vv), value(ff), interpolation(ss) {}

};

obj easy(vector<int>(), 0.25, "bezier");
```

When I need to create who-knows what kind of object on a whim, It's extremely inefficient and a huge waste of time to manually write a parameterized constructor for every object I need.  In Python, I can essentially avoid this with dictionaries; however, unordered_maps in C++ must map to the same datatype, so they aren't really what I'm looking for.

Essentially, I'm just wanting an easy way to create a simple object which acts as a collection of items of various datatypes and nothing more.  Can this be done in C++ 11, and if so, how?

Comment: struct / class is the way to go. If you don't like writing constructors, let your IDE do the job.

Comment: You can achieve this using templates, with [variadic templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Comment: There is also [std::tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/)

Comment: @nada `tuple` is cool, but it was designed to use in case of generic programing (for example store variadic arguments, so later they could be used by `std::apply`). I hate `tuple` in none template code. It makes code harder to read and maintain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> It's extremely inefficient and a huge waste of time to manually write
>   a parameterized constructor for every object I need.

I completely agree. However, there is no problem, as you actually do not need to write a constructor for each and every simple struct:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct obj
{
    std::vector<int> keyframe_range;
    float value;
    std::string interpolation;
};

int main() {
    obj easy{ {}, 0.25, "bezier"};
    std::cout << easy.value << " " << easy.interpolation;        
}
```

It is called [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) and can be done when the class has

> - no private or protected direct (since C++17)non-static data members
> - no user-declared constructors (until C++11)
> - no user-provided constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11) (until C++17)
> - no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++17) (until
>     C++20)
> - no user-declared or inherited constructors
>     [...]

and a couple of more restrictions, that usually all apply for such simple structs (they are called aggregates).

> Essentially, I'm just wanting an easy way to create a simple object
>   which acts as a collection of items of various datatypes and nothing
>   more. Can this be done in C++ 11, and if so, how?

Alternatively you should take a look at `std::tuple`, though writing your own class has the benefit of giving the members meaningful names and you can distinguish types that as [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) would be exactly the same.

On the other hand, the advantage of `std::tuple` is that it comes with a couple of operators (eg `operator<`) already defined. Hence depending on your use case you can choose one or the other.

Comment: The one down side to this, pre C++20, is that you still have to implement the comparison operators.  Once we get `auto operator(type const&)<=> = default;`  it will be really nice.

Comment: @NathanOliver, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @ereHsaWyhsipS With this approach using `obj`, you can't have two `obj`'s and compare them like `obj1 == obj2` Because there is no `operator ==` defined for `obj`.  You would have to write that code if you want that.  In my answer, `tuple` has this already for you so you don't have to write any extra code.  That said, in C++20 we will get the spaceship operator `operator <=>` and you'll be able to default it to have the compiler build all the logical operators for you by adding to `obj` `auto operator(obj const&)<=> = default;`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) for this.  It lets you create an object of heterogeneous types, without having to specify all of that boiler plate.  It does have a down side though.  You can't give the members of a tuple a name.  You have to access them via the "index" they are (the first member is index 0) or the type (this only works if you don't duplicate the types).  So

```
easy = {"keyframe_range":[], "value":0.25, "interpolation":"bezier"}
```

would become

```
auto easy = std::tuple<std::vector<int>, float, std::string>{{}, 0.25, "bezier"}
```

ans you would access the members like `std::get<1>(easy)`/`std::get<float>(easy)` to get the `float` member.

---

C++17: You can use a [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to get named access to the members like

```
auto&[easy_vec, easy_float, easy_string] = easy;
```

and now `easy_vec`, `easy_float`, and `easy_string` are references to the tuple members.